# How initialize "editing cycle" of items when you press Enter?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Consider below snippet:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.Qt import *  # noqa


class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyTable()
    w.setColumnCount(1)
    w.setRowCount(16)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm trying is initialize "editing cycle" of items when you press Enter. How to achieve this?

Comment: Is the convert function just for demonstration purpose, or you actually just need to change the content to uppercase? In short, you actually need the user to be able to input only two hexadecimal digits (or "-", which I suppose it's for no input)?

Comment: Please once question per post, if you have another question then create another post, those are the SO rules

Comment: @eyllanesc Yeah, I was aware of what you're saying but even so, it still doesn't feel right to duplicate content across SO post to ask related questions... Anyway, opened another thread :/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66293798/how-to-apply-post-transformation-on-qitemdelegate

Comment: @BPL Why would you have to duplicate? You must provide an MRE that focuses on the problem, for example see that I edit your post for the appropriate MRE. When you have several questions in the same, you complicate the search that another user can do.

Comment: @eyllanesc Fair enough, yeah, if you see it that way, makes total sense what you're saying there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the editing of an item to start when the enter key is pressed then you must override the keyPressEvent() method and call edit() when necessary:

```py
class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setItemDelegate(MyCell())
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

        if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return):
            if not self.edit(
                self.currentIndex(), QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed, event
            ):
                event.ignore()
```