# How to apply post transformation on QItemDelegate?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Consider below snippet:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.Qt import *  # noqa


class MyCell(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        w = QLineEdit(parent)
        validator = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^$|[0-9A-Fa-f]{1}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-]"))
        w.setValidator(validator)

        def convert():
            w.setText(w.text().upper().zfill(2))

        w.returnPressed.connect(convert)

        return w


class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setItemDelegate(MyCell())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyTable()
    w.setColumnCount(1)
    w.setRowCount(16)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How would you apply the convert function not only when returnPressed signal is emitted but also when you're editing and suddenly you switch focus to another item using the mouse?

Comment: @musicamante No, that's a different question that was addressed already perfectly in that post, please take a look to this [video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rtlzbjtke9f6162/2021-02-20_17-23-27.mp4), as you can see... I'm editing the item there and when i switch to another item the `convert` function won't be called... so the idea is figure out how to achieve that :/

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've just seen the edit on the other one. Anyway, you didn't answer what I asked there: Is the convert function just for demonstration purpose, or you actually just need to change the content to uppercase? In short, you actually need the user to be able to input only two hexadecimal digits (or "-", which I suppose it's for no input)?

Comment: @musicamante Yeah, hehe, I didn't have the time yet to answer your previous question... in short, an item should contain either "-" (empty cell) or (0-255) numbers in hexadecimal, other type of output shouldn't be allowed on the table, and also they should be in upper case... I'm writing some sort of music tracker so those cells are containing "patterns" of notes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it is better to do the transformation when the data is saved in the model:

```py
class MyCell(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        w = QLineEdit(parent)
        validator = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("[0-9A-Fa-f]{1}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}|[-]"))
        w.setValidator(validator)
        return w

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        text = editor.text().upper().zfill(2)
        model.setData(index, text)
```

Comment: Super awesome! I love your solution. Btw... when you select multiple cells, you press enter and you edit your item... is there any way to apply the output to all cells? Can this be achieved on the QItemDelegate or it needs to be done at the QTableWidget level?

Comment: @BPL From what I understand you select let's say 3 elements then you press enter and it opens from one of its editors then you want that when enter is pressed (or the focus is changed) that text is copied in the other selected items, am I right? Right? It would be in both since you have to detect that the editor was closed and then send a signal to the view where it copies the content of the edited cell to the other selected cells.

Comment: @BPL I am not going to extend the discussion about other functionalities since that is not the objective of the comments, so I recommend you try what I indicate and if it does not work for you then you must publish a new post indicating your intent

Comment: Yeah, sure, I'll give it a shot and if I get stuck I'll publish a new post about it later on... Hopefully I figure out how to avoid notifying the parent from the delegate as that'd be bad code. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @BPL Create a signal in the delegate, something like `closed = pyqtSignal(QModelIndex)` and then you connect the signal of the delegate with a method of the view, so you keep everything decoupled (that's the magic of Qt signals)